# Can't create a key of the Subject <'MyCAContainerName'>

Tags: certificate, makecert

using `makecert` i have written the commade:

> makecert -pe -n "CN=Myauthority" -sr localmachine -ss Root -a sha256 -cy authority -r -sk MyCAContainerName -sky exchange -sp  "Microsoft RSA Schannel Cryptographic Provider " -sy 12 -len 2048 certif.cer;

i recieved an error

> Error: Can't create the key of the Subject <'MyCAContainerName'>

In seeking the solution, I discovered that the problem arises because I did not Authorizations on `machineKey` file : (`C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` ), the

following link explains better what I'm saying;

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/278381

I followed the same procedures in order to have enough permissions to the a machine key, but the problem is always posed

Answer (score 5):

It seems that `Can't create the key of the subject` is a fairly generic error, however, what follows after it may give a clue.

While it may be caused by permissions errors (e.g. [makecert.exe error: Can't create the key of the subject](http://nerdwords.blogspot.com/2008/01/makecertexe-error-can-create-key-of.html)), I have also seen the error of the form `Can't create the key of the subject ('<some guid>')` caused by an incorrect parameter to the `-sp` argument.

In your case, `Error: Can't create the key of the Subject <'MyCAContainerName'>` would make me guess that there is something wrong with the `-sk MyCAContainerName` portion of the command, but the upshot is, if it is not something with permissions, than it is likely an incorrect command argument or combination of arguments.

Comment: Thanks.  It seems that I can never use `-sp "Microsoft RSA SChannel Cryptographic Provider" -sy 12` even though this CSP is valid according to the explanation for these options on the [makecert page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bfsktky3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) (i.e. they are in the registry.)

Answer (score 4):

Master,

I Ran on the same error. I solved it running command prompt as an administrator user.

MV

Answer (score 1):

Its late but I have the solution to this. First execute the command as you are, it will give the error `Error: Can't create the key of the Subject <'MyCAContainerName'>`. But it will create a `.pvk` file. ***Don't delete it***. Instead execute the command again, but this time remove `-sk MyCAContainerName` from the command. And it will create your certificate.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the C drive did not have enough space. I cleared some unwanted files and folders and it worked.